# Create custom shape with holes

Tags: pstricks

I'd like to create a key shape symbol using `PSTricks`, but I have some problems filling it...

Here's the shape I'd like :

```
\documentclass[pstricks, float]{standalone}
usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-circ, pst-plot,
    pst-3dplot,pst-solides3d, pst-sigsys, pstricks-add,pst-eucl}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[labelangle=:U, showgrid=true](-3, -3)(5, 3)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green]{
        \psarc[]{-}(0.2, 0){0.8}{25}{346}     % Exterior disk
        \pscircle[linewidth=2pt](0, 0){0.25}  % Hole

        \psline[]{-}(0.9250, 0.3380)(3, 0.3380)(3.3, 0)(3, -0.3420)(2.8, -0.3420)
        (2.8, -0.3420)(2.65, -0.1920)(2.55, -0.3420)(2.45, -0.1920)(2.25, -0.4920)
        (2.15, -0.3420)(2.05, -0.4920)(1.95, -0.3420)(1.85, -0.4920)(1.65, -0.1920)
        (1.55, -0.3420)(1.45, -0.1920)(1.25, -0.4920)(1.05, -0.1935)(0.9762, -0.1935)
    }   
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

But the `pscustom` doesn't work as expected.

Here's the result :

[image: MWE result]

I have thus two problems :

1. Create a closed shape with the `\psarc` and the `\psline`
2. Scoop the `\pscircle` out of the shape

I haven't find the commands in the user's manual that allows me to do so, and I hope I'm wrong...

**Besides, that I'd like to turn the key shape into a new PS object**, let's say a `\psKey`, that could be filled, linestyle-d, and so on... I know it's about the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` but I could get proper results...

Is this structure wrong ? Should I save it as psKey.tex ?

```
\makeatletter
\def\tor(#1){%
    \rput(#1){%
        %
        % Code lines of the key drawing
        %
        }
    }
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3, -3)(5, 3)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green]{
       \psarcn(0.2, 0){0.8}{346}{25}     % Exterior disk
        \psline(3, 0.3380)(3.3, 0)(3, -0.3420)(2.8, -0.3420)
        (2.8, -0.3420)(2.65, -0.1920)(2.55, -0.3420)(2.45, -0.1920)(2.25, -0.4920)
        (2.15, -0.3420)(2.05, -0.4920)(1.95, -0.3420)(1.85, -0.4920)(1.65, -0.1920)
        (1.55, -0.3420)(1.45, -0.1920)(1.25, -0.4920)(1.05, -0.1935)(0.9762, -0.1935)
        \pscircle[linewidth=2pt](0, 0){0.25}  % Hole
     }   
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For creating a new macro for this look into `pstricks-add` there you'll find a lot of examples, like this one:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\makeatletter
\def\pstKey{\pst@object{pstKey}}
\def\pstKey@i{\@ifnextchar({\pstKey@ii{0}}\pstKey@ii}
\def\pstKey@ii#1(#2){%
  \addbefore@par{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green}%
  \begingroup
  \use@par
  \rput{#1}(#2){%
    \pscustom{
       \psarcn(0.2, 0){0.8}{346}{25}     % Exterior disk
        \psline(3, 0.3380)(3.3, 0)(3, -0.3420)(2.8, -0.3420)
        (2.8, -0.3420)(2.65, -0.1920)(2.55, -0.3420)(2.45, -0.1920)(2.25, -0.4920)
        (2.15, -0.3420)(2.05, -0.4920)(1.95, -0.3420)(1.85, -0.4920)(1.65, -0.1920)
        (1.55, -0.3420)(1.45, -0.1920)(1.25, -0.4920)(1.05, -0.1935)(0.9762, -0.1935)
        \pscircle[linewidth=2pt](0, 0){0.25}  % Hole
     }}%   
  \endgroup\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-3, -3)(5, 3)
\pstKey(0,0)
\pstKey[fillcolor=red,opacity=0.5]{90}(2,-2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And with a scaling option:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\makeatletter
\def\pstKey{\pst@object{pstKey}}
\def\pstKey@i{\@ifnextchar({\pstKey@ii{0}}\pstKey@ii}
\def\pstKey@ii#1(#2){%
  \addbefore@par{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green}%
  \begingroup
  \use@par
  \rput{#1}(#2){\psscalebox{\psk@psscale}{%
    \pscustom{
       \psarcn(0.2, 0){0.8}{346}{25}     % Exterior disk
        \psline(3, 0.3380)(3.3, 0)(3, -0.3420)(2.8, -0.3420)
        (2.8, -0.3420)(2.65, -0.1920)(2.55, -0.3420)(2.45, -0.1920)(2.25, -0.4920)
        (2.15, -0.3420)(2.05, -0.4920)(1.95, -0.3420)(1.85, -0.4920)(1.65, -0.1920)
        (1.55, -0.3420)(1.45, -0.1920)(1.25, -0.4920)(1.05, -0.1935)(0.9762, -0.1935)
        \pscircle[linewidth=2pt](0, 0){0.25}  % Hole
     }}}%
  \endgroup\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[bgcolor=yellow!30](-3, -3)(5, 3)
\pstKey(0,0)
\pstKey[fillcolor=red,psscale=0.5,opacity=0.5]{90}(2,-1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks ! And How can I turn this *marvel* into a `symbol` ?

Comment: as I already wrote, have a look into pst-platon or pst-fractal. There are a lot of examples.

Comment: OK, thanks. Actually, I though you quoted `pstricks-add` for the \pscustom, not for the symbol. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: How can I do to resize it ? `psunit = 0.2` also affect the placement on the grid.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Nice, thank you very much ! Sorry, I have just one other problem : I must use `\psset{RoundCorners}` for other objects, and I can't put thses after the `\psKey`. How can I prevent the command to have effect on the key ?

Comment: `\addbefore@par{...,RoundCorners}`

Comment: I haven't been precise. I have, previously in my code, a `\psset{style = RoundCorners}` command (from pst-sigsys), and I dont want it to have effect on the lines \psKey

Comment: `\addbefore@par{...,linestyle=solid,linearc=0}`

Comment: It's still the same... I've posted a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269200/interferencs-between-pstricks-options)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to add the inner circle outside the `\pscustom`.

I defined a `\pstKey` command through several lists of empty nodes, so as to ease the modification of parameters. `pstKey` can be placed anywhere and rotated, with `\rput`.

```
\documentclass[float]{standalone}%
\PassOptionsToPackage{table, dvipsnames, x11names}{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-circ, pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d,pst-eucl}%, pst-sigsys

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand\pstKey{\pnodes{U}(3.3, 0)(3, 0.3380)(0.9250, 0.3380)%
\pnodes{b}(0.9762, -0.1935)(1.05, -0.1935)(1.45, -0.1920)(1.65, -0.1920)(2.45, -0.1920)(2.65, -0.1920)
\pnodes{m}(1.55, -0.3420)(1.95, -0.3420)(2.15, -0.3420)(2.55, -0.3420)(2.8, -0.3420)(3, -0.3420)
\pnodes{B}(1.25, -0.4920)(1.85, -0.4920)(2.05, -0.4920)(2.25, -0.4920)
%
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Gold4!40! HoneyDew4, opacity =0.65, linejoin =1]{%
\psline(U0)(U1)(U2)
 \psarc(0.2, 0){0.8}{25}{346} % Exterior disk
\psline(b0)(b1)(B0)(b2)(m0)(b3)(B1)(m1)(B2)(m2)(B3)(b4)(m3)(b5)(m4)(m5)(U0)
  }
  \pscircle[linewidth=2pt, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white](0, 0){0.25}% Hole
  }%

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[labelangle=:U, showgrid=true](-3, -3)(5, 3)%
    \rput{-30}(1,1){\pstKey}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: change the background color and the inner circle will still be filled with white instead of the background.

Comment: That's what I did first and it didn't work. I guess I mixed up in various modifications of the O.P.'s code. Thank you, Herbert!

Answer (score 0):

List of changes:

- replace the last point with `\closepath` to fix the discontinuity at that point (it is noticeable for thick `linewidth`).
- move `linewidth=2pt` to `pscustom` as `linewidth` declared inside `pscustom` does not take any effect.
- remove the center of the last circle.
- use 2 decimal  points for literal numbers.
- remove unnecessary `pstricks-add`.
- reduce the canvas size.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-1,-1)(4, 1)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green,linewidth=2pt]{
       \psarcn(0.2,0){0.8}{346}{25}
        \psline(3,0.33)(3.3,0)(3,-0.34)(2.8,-0.34)
                    (2.8,-0.34)(2.65,-0.19)(2.55,-0.34)(2.45,-0.19)(2.25,-0.49)
                    (2.15,-0.34)(2.05,-0.49)(1.95,-0.34)(1.85,-0.49)(1.65,-0.19)
                    (1.55,-0.34)(1.45,-0.19)(1.25,-0.49)(1.05,-0.19)%(0.9762,-0.1935)
        \closepath
        \pscircle{0.25}
     }   
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]