# Interferencs between PSTricks options

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add, pst-sigsys

I'm making a building to explain the [asymmetric encryption scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) to my students. I'm using `pst-sigsys` to designe the Block Diagram, and `pstricks-add` to draw the key :

[image: Result]

I had problems designing the key, but I already received answers (see my [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269050/create-custom-shape-with-holes/)).

The thing is, I have now interferences between `pst-sigsys` *RoundCorners* options, and the actual drawing of the key.

I want the keys to be **above** the frames (not like in the picture). But, in the code, if I put them after the frames (see MWE), the `RoundCorners` option modifies the key.  M. Voß already brought a partial solution, but it didn't entierly work, so that's why I posted a new question.

Here's the MWE that causes this to happen :

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, float]{standalone}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-circ, pst-plot, pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d, pst-sigsys, pstricks-add, pst-eucl}

%% DEFINITION OF THE KEY DRAWING
\makeatletter
\def\pstKey{\pst@object{pstKey}}
\def\pstKey@i{\@ifnextchar({\pstKey@ii{0}}\pstKey@ii}
\def\pstKey@ii#1(#2){%
  \addbefore@par{fillstyle=solid, linestyle=solid,linearc=0, framearc=0, framesep=0}%
  \begingroup
  \use@par
  \rput{#1}(#2){\psscalebox{\psk@psscale}{%
    \pscustom{
       \psarcn(-1.3, 0){0.8}{346}{25}     % Exterior disk
        \psline(1.5, 0.3380)(1.8, 0)(1.5, -0.3420)(1.3, -0.3420)
        (1.3, -0.3420)(1.15, -0.1920)(1.05, -0.3420)(0.95, -0.1920)(0.75, -0.4920)
        (0.65, -0.3420)(0.55, -0.4920)(0.45, -0.3420)(0.35, -0.4920)(0.15, -0.1920)
        (0.05, -0.3420)(-0.05, -0.1920)(-0.25, -0.4920)(-0.45, -0.1935)(-0.5238, -0.1935)
        \pscircle[linewidth=2pt](-1.5, 0){0.25}  % Hole
     }}}%
  \endgroup\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
%% END OF DEFINITION


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[labelangle=:U, showgrid=false](-4, -1.5)(10, 3)


    \pssignal(-3, 0.5){hbob}{\parbox[c]{1.5\psunit}{\centering \texttt{Hello Bob}}}
    \pssignal(3, 0.5){ciph}{\parbox[c]{2\psunit}{\centering \texttt{x0Ak3o\$2Rj}}}
    \pssignal(9, 0.5){hbob2}{\parbox[c]{1.5\psunit}{\centering \texttt{Hello Bob}}}

    %\psdot % Mark the origin of the axes

    \psset{style = RoundCorners, gratioWh=1.8,style=Arrow}%, arrowinset=0}
    \pssignal(-1.5, 2.3){key}{\parbox[c]{3\psunit}{\centering \textcolor{ForestGreen}{Public Key}}}
    \pssignal(4.5, -1){key}{\parbox[c]{3\psunit}{\centering \textcolor{WildStrawberry}{Private Key}}}
    \pssignal(0, 2.5){key1}{}
    \pssignal(6, 2.5){key2}{}       

    \psfblock[framesize=1.75 1.2](0, 0.5){rsa1}{\parbox[c]{2\psunit}{\centering RSA}}
    \psfblock[framesize=1.75 1.2](6, 0.5){rsa2}{\parbox[c]{2\psunit}{\centering RSA}}


    \nclist{ncline}{hbob, rsa1, ciph, rsa2, hbob2}



    \pstKey[psscale=0.5, fillcolor=ForestGreen]{-90}(0,1.6)
    \pstKey[psscale=-0.5, fillcolor=WildStrawberry]{-90}(6,-0.6)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Running that makes the key different than the actual drawing. I looked in the `psy-sigsys` doc, and I reset all the options included in the `RoundCorners` : `linearc=0, framearc=0, framesep=0` but apparently it isn't enough...

Comment: I don't see any problems as I compile to [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I9bn4.png). Perhaps you need to update your distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold the `\psset{RoundCorners,...}` local with `\bgroup ... \egroup` or `{...}` or `\begingroup ... \endgroup`:

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, float]{standalone}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-circ, pst-plot, pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d, pst-sigsys,
    pst-eucl,pstricks-add}

%% DEFINITION OF THE KEY DRAWING
\makeatletter
\def\pstKey{\pst@object{pstKey}}
\def\pstKey@i{\@ifnextchar({\pstKey@ii{0}}\pstKey@ii}
\def\pstKey@ii#1(#2){%
  \begingroup
  \addbefore@par{fillstyle=solid,linestyle=solid,linearc=0}%
  \use@par
  \rput{#1}(#2){\psscalebox{\psk@psscale}{%
    \pscustom{
       \psarcn(-1.3, 0){0.8}{346}{25}     % Exterior disk
        \psline(1.5, 0.3380)(1.8, 0)(1.5, -0.3420)(1.3, -0.3420)
        (1.3, -0.3420)(1.15, -0.1920)(1.05, -0.3420)(0.95, -0.1920)(0.75, -0.4920)
        (0.65, -0.3420)(0.55, -0.4920)(0.45, -0.3420)(0.35, -0.4920)(0.15, -0.1920)
        (0.05, -0.3420)(-0.05, -0.1920)(-0.25, -0.4920)(-0.45, -0.1935)(-0.5238, -0.1935)
        \pscircle[linewidth=2pt](-1.5, 0){0.25}  % Hole
     }}}%
  \endgroup\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
%% END OF DEFINITION


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[labelangle=:U, showgrid=false](-4, -2)(10, 3)
    \pssignal(-3, 0.5){hbob}{\parbox[c]{1.5\psunit}{\centering \texttt{Hello Bob}}}
    \pssignal(3, 0.5){ciph}{\parbox[c]{2\psunit}{\centering \texttt{x0Ak3o\$2Rj}}}
    \pssignal(9, 0.5){hbob2}{\parbox[c]{1.5\psunit}{\centering \texttt{Hello Bob}}}

    %\psdot % Mark the origin of the axes
    \bgroup
    \psset{style = RoundCorners, gratioWh=1.8,style=Arrow}%, arrowinset=0}
    \pssignal(-1.5, 2.3){key}{\parbox[c]{3\psunit}{\centering \textcolor{ForestGreen}{Public Key}}}
    \pssignal(4.5, -1){key}{\parbox[c]{3\psunit}{\centering \textcolor{WildStrawberry}{Private Key}}}
    \pssignal(0, 2.5){key1}{}
    \pssignal(6, 2.5){key2}{}       

    \psfblock[framesize=1.75 1.2](0, 0.5){rsa1}{\parbox[c]{2\psunit}{\centering RSA}}
    \psfblock[framesize=1.75 1.2](6, 0.5){rsa2}{\parbox[c]{2\psunit}{\centering RSA}}

    \nclist{ncline}{hbob, rsa1, ciph, rsa2, hbob2}
    \egroup
    \pstKey[psscale=0.5, fillcolor=ForestGreen]{-90}(0,1.6)
    \pstKey[psscale=-0.5, fillcolor=WildStrawberry]{-90}(6,-0.6)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I thought I'll be a bigger deal... Shame on me :)